# ASP.NET Get value from Radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have the following radionbuttonlist in the ASPX:

```
Line 62:    <td class="auto-style6">2 Gender</td>
Line 63:    <td>
Line 64:    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblGender" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblGender_SelectedIndexChanged">
Line 65:        <asp:ListItem Value="Male">Male</asp:ListItem>
Line 66:            <asp:ListItem Value="Female">Female</asp:ListItem>
Line 67:        </asp:RadioButtonList>
Line 68:    </td>
```

I am trying to get the selected value of a checked radio button (Male/Female) and display it in a textfield when I click a button.

I thought it should be something really easy, and I have the following code in c#.

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtGender.Text = rblGender.SelectedValue;
}
```

Everything can compile without any errors. However when I run the web form in the browser and click the `btnTest`, the browser shows the following error:
It also highlighted the above code snippet at **line 64** in red.

> **Compiler Error Message**: CS1061: 'ASP.userForm_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'rblGender_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'rblGender_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.userForm_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Question**: What did I missed out or done wrongly?

*There are other questions with this topic in SO, however theirs could be easily fixed using `.selectedValue`. When I tried mine, it gives me the above error.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple update your onselectedindexchanged event to point to btnTest_Click or setup the event you have named in onselectedindexchanged: rblGender_SelectedIndexChanged.  The error is just saying you dont have the event wired up correctly.

Comment: Yup, I just found out that too. I still have some questions though. Can I just remove those "onselectedindexchanged" stuff. Is it safe to remove it? I tried it, it works without problem. I mean, by convention, can I just remove it if I am not gonna detect an radio button state change?

Comment: You can remove it and not fire the event every time its changed, then on any other event just make the same call to get the SelectedValue.  Please mark as answered :)

Comment: Even though I also managed to find the root cause, but you answered my question and you found the cause too. I will accept your answer. And +1 for your reply. You can +1 my solution too! =P

Answer (score 1):

I also found the cause of the problem actually.

It was because of `"OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblGender_SelectedIndexChanged"`, they are expecting me to write a method in C# to handle radiobutton state change but I didn't include that in my C# codes.

When I remove it and write is as:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblGender" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
```

everything works fine.